# effect of doping on recombination rate

Tags: semiconductors

As we already know that for an intrinsic semiconductor, the relation between recombination rate (r) and intrinsic carrier concentration (n) is given as the following:

> $$r = a \cdot n^2$$

where a: recombination coefficient.

My question is will recombination rate (r) increase or decrease or remain same with doping.

Comment: increases with doping

Comment: will it depend on the dopant. I mean will it increase in both cases where my dopant is a donor or an acceptor.

Comment: irrespective of dopant type, unless both types are added to the same intrinsic material

Comment: thank you very much. you can write it as answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: That's fine. Happy learning...

Answer (score 2):

[image: undoped]

Firstly think about intrinsic semiconductor. When thermal equilibrium satisfied excess holes and electrons are equal. $$n=p$$

Think about electrons at the conduction band. They want to recombine with holes to decreases their energy states.

[image: doped2]

When you add donors to semiconductor now there are more electrons want to recombine with fixed holes. Therefore **recombination rate** must be larger.

All figures are taken Middle East Technical University EE212 Lecture Notes of Prof Dr Cengiz Beşikçi